# is it possible to use css to control another css element?

Tags: css

For instance say:

```
.vis {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Could I use something like this?

```
.p:hover .vis {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what  you mean.

Comment: That is something you could easily try yourself.... no?

Comment: Say when I hover over a and element with a p class and it's nesting say a span with a hidden class can i change that hidden class values when I hover over that p class

Comment: Are you trying to change the `.vis` class whenever you hover over the `.p` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to an extent. The key is that the element you're "watching" for, say, a mouseover, has to be a parent of the affected element (you currently can't traverse the DOM upward using only CSS), but you can make it look like certain elements are affecting sibling elements with some clever CSS. If you don't want the affected element to change when it's being hovered, you'll have to explicitly set that, though.

(Random factoid - this is the basis for how pure CSS suckerfish menus are created.)

[Here's a fiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/uZMhw/)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible - read about the [cascade and inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) rules of CSS.

Comment: @Oded... hey, would you mind giving an example, or creating a fiddle to show how this works? I'm curious... :)